# How set dynamically parameter properties in Visual Studio report?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to set dynamically the parameters properties in the VisaulStudio Report.
[image: Parameters]

I need to set the values in the properties by company caller.
[image: Propertirs]

If I call the report from company **A** I neeed to set the *Nullable* with *True* value, otherwhise I need to set with *False* value.

I'm able to call different *design report*, but I don't know how to steer theese properties.
I use VisualStudio 2013.

Comment: Could you give us a bit of background on this requirement? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Data contract class `LedgerClosingContract` has method `parmIncludeTransactions` used from `LedgerClosingDP.processReport()`. You can modify the report logic in X++ as needed.

Comment: I think that only lets you set the value of the parameter, but not the property `Nullable`.

Comment: @FH-Inway, the background of the requirement is not clear, as you mentioned in another comment. I have clarified how SSRS report parameter-related requirements are normally approached in Dynamics AX. I believe it will help ulisses achieve whatever's required. If not, ulisses will clarify.